# Undefined method `+' on Heroku RoR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku

I'm developing a small application in Ruby-On-Rails. In a controller I have this piece of code:

```
@user = User.find(current_user.id)
@user.number = current_user.number + 1
@user.save!
```

Although it locally runs without problems, it crashes on Heroku at line two, with the following error:

NoMethodError (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass)

Any tips on how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are storing the number as attribute in your database you should set the default state to 0.

create new migration and regenerate the number column.

```
def change
  remove_colum :users, :number
  add_column users, :number, :integer, :default => 0

  #ensure that all users with number == nil have got 0 instead nil 
  User.where(:number => nil).update_all(:number => 0)
end
```

Comment: This should be done for the CurrentUser class perhaps? I'm confused

Comment: usually current_user is a helper from authentication and it is the user instance in there. Try out call current_user.class you should get the User class.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this too:

```
@user.number = current_user ? current_user.to_i : 0
@user.save!
```